# Multidimensional array initialization brackets

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, initialization

```
int a[][3]={{1,2,3},11,2,3,4,5};

int a[][3]={1,2,3,11,2,3,4,5};
```

Is there any difference between those two? Are they the same for the compiler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure they're the same due to *6.7.8 Initialization, 20* (C99):

> 20. If the aggregate or union contains elements or members that are aggregates or unions,
>       these rules apply recursively to the subaggregates or contained unions. If the initializer of
>       a subaggregate or contained union begins with a left brace, the initializers enclosed by
>       that brace and its matching right brace initialize the elements or members of the
>       subaggregate or the contained union. Otherwise, only enough initializers from the list are
>       taken to account for the elements or members of the subaggregate or the first member of
>       the contained union; any remaining initializers are left to initialize the next element or
>       member of the aggregate of which the current subaggregate or contained union is a part.

You're initializing a subarray (of size 3).

In the first version `{1,2,3}` is used for that due to the explicit braces.

In the second version there are no braces, so the next three values (`1,2,3`) are taken from the initializer list.